# OBS-websocket windowed projector geometry

Tags: qt, obs

I am fighting since several days in order to open a windowed projector with OBS-Websocket.

The OBS-Websocket documentation says that the projectorGeometry is a string for "*Size/Position data for a windowed projector, in Qt Base64 encoded format*".

I've been searching the Qt documentation and found information on `QWindow::setGeometry`, but nothing for a string for "*Size/Position data for a windowed projector, in Qt Base64 encoded format*".

I've tried several combinations of JSON data plus Base64 encoding, but nothing works.

Is there any description or example somewhere?

Comment: Do you really need `projectorGeometry`? Can't you just use `monitorIndex`? Seems that the geometry data is some internal format used between `QWidget::saveGeometry` and `QWidget::restoreGeometry`. Seems unclear how are you expected to use that.

Comment: You might find some useful info [here](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/pull/338#issuecomment-673529947)

Comment: I am using obs-websocket from powershell script. Full screen prrojector is working perfectly using monitorIndex. However I need to display 3 sources in separated windows because there is not enough displays on the system.... I had a look to saveGeometry and I'll dig in... As far as I understand the starting point is an array of x1, x2, y1, y2 which is converted in Base64 thru specific method. Many thanks for your help. I'll be back if I need more help.